# Different timevalues in tool make service area ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, time

In ModelBuilder i want to make a lot of service area layers.
The input data would be the same but the day of time would change every time.
So from 6:00:00 untill 22:00:00
i created already a table with the different times (in format date) (see figure 2)
and add this table into the model (see figure 3)

now when i add %Value% in the field day of time (see figure 4) and click next on the  button ok.. nothing happend, the field of day of the time is again empty..

So how could i run the tool 'make service layer' for different time steps?

[image: value_service layer]

[image: time table]

[image: time in model]

And how does it works to change the output name automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niels,

Looks like a bug in model builder. I was able to replicate the problem too. But I did find a simple solution.

1. In the image below note that my date values have a date component and not just a time.
2. In the Make Service Area Layer tool I added %n% to the layer name to give each layer a unique name ending with a number (the number of times the model had run), your current set up will overwrite, may be you wanted that, something to be aware of?
3. I was able to connect the output of the iterator to the time of day parameter by using the connect tool and not writing %Value%. Why that would work and not the usual in-line substitution I have no idea!
4. Output of iterator was set to **Date** type.

[image: Modelbuilder example]

Comment: It works, thank you!

BTW: if you chose in the field 'day of time ' time only , it's possible to work only with hours and not with the date